# Creating a procedural stone texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, procedural

I am trying to create a really worn-out stone texture. Here are some images similar to what I'm looking for:

[image][image]

I'm looking for something that looks like the first image. Dirty and greyish-black. But I want it cracked like the second image. What kind of procedural texture nodes can/should I use for this? Here's what I got so far:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a little vague what you want because the diffuse color of the two images are different. Do you want it dirty or clean for instance?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Realistic is subjective.

Comment: @Gunslinger Sorry about that. I'm looking for something like the first image. Dirty and grey, but cracked like the second image.

Comment: No worries. In a couple of hours I will have some free time and I have this exact problem on the table. I plan to release it as a youtube tutorial later (if it goes well) but hopefully I will have a sufficient node-group answer soon.

Answer (score 6):

I have made a node setup that renders like this:

[image: Rendered stone]

It consists of two diffuse shaders. One is your stone texture from above (well almost). The other is a simple green "dirt" material. The real trick is to combine the dirt with the stone in a believable pattern. I tried multiplying two noise textures with some distortion. Distortion makes noise be liked two colors of paint where you have stirred it some. You get a swirling pattern.

To get this further, I would add some bump to the dirt shader. Also, I would bake an AO map and use that in the mask, letting it influence the mask so that there is more dirt in crevices.

Here is the node setup.

[image: Node setup]

Answer (score 6):

Here is another attempt, using [*Musgrave* noise](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Textures#Musgrave_Texture) to create an overall uneven distribution to the dirt:

[image]

Material node setup:

[image]

The *Voronoi Crackle* node group:

[image]

Here is the [blendfile](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/25874).

Comment: The **Difference** method for mixing cells is quite smart.

Comment: The cracks link seems to be gone @LeonCheung

Comment: @fabriced indeed. Unfortunately I cannot remember what I did and how. Sorry man.