# Improve texture rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders

I cannot understand why my rendering looks so fake.
Can you give me your advices ?
[image]

Here it is nodes shader :

[image]

EDIT :

I would like to get this object modeled
[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, it would help to know what object you're trying to achieve, do you have a picture?

Comment: I have updated my post, thank you @moonboots

Comment: these are columns, your object seems flat. Apart from that, your object looks like modern, clean and brand new plastic or metal, while what you show is old stone monument, so it needs much more bump, spots, accidents, etc...

Comment: Okay thank you for your avices. Would you agree to receive my file to apply your advices and show me ?

Comment: maybe check this for the texture: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5699/creating-a-procedural-stone-texture ... also, you need to create some real bumps on your topology (you can use the Sculpt mode for that)

Comment: It's super nice @moonboots Thanks again !